# api for sending advertisements in android

Tags: android

I have to make an Android application in which my client would show certain advertisements that he has.

He has asked me for a proper framework that can be used on the Android plaform so that he can use it to add the ads he wants, while I would, on the phone end, integrate the advertisment feature (using the advertisement provider's API to display the advertisement).

Is this arrangement possible? If so, which would be the best API for me to use? It does not matter if it is paid or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have an idea :) Use Admob Ads SDK in your application. And then client orders ad from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Use Adwhirl from Admob, and you display house ads in addition to Admob ads. You can use ads from any amount of networks as well.

https://www.adwhirl.com/

Comment: do they have a API that i have to integrate in my application? Have you tried using this before ? How was your experience?

Comment: Sorry I have not used it, but I have used Admob API, which was really simple, and since Adwhirl is made by Admob I imagine the simplicity would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Consider house ads in Admob, they are very easy to set up and use.  You can set your app to 100% house ads.

[MobFox](http://www.mobfox.com/publisher?aid=678) has a flexible adserver feature in addition to house ads, but I haven't tested it yet.